# Docker build failure when doing COPY --from=composer (mediaType in manifest should be v2 not v1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, manifest, aws-codebuild

Preface: I'm new to docker

I'm using AWS and CodeBuild to deploy my app to ECS. When it gets to this line in my Dockerfile it fails -

```
Step 21/47 : COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
latest: Pulling from library/composer
invalid from flag value composer:latest: mediaType in manifest should be 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' not 'application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json'
```

This just started happening with no changes to the Dockerfile. Although, the composer image was updated within the same hour this started happening.

What I've tried -

- I tried doing `docker manifest inspect composer` and received a `no such manifest` result.
- I also tried building locally with the same Dockerfile and it succeeded with no errors.

I don't really understand what I need to do to fix this. Is docker expecting a v2 manifest but the composer image is packaged with a v1 manifest? Or vice versa? And how does one update the manifest?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Often, when people use the `--from` option in a COPY statement, the source is an earlier stage in the Dockerfile. It seems like you don't have a stage called `composer`, so docker tries copying from the official composer image on Docker Hub. That's unusual. Is that what you expect to happen?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Removing the `aws-ecs` tag as this is happening before you ever attempt to deploy to ECS, so that is an unrelated tag. Adding the `aws-codebuild` tag because the error is happening during a build running on CodeBuild. Although I would suggest you try to build the docker image locally and see if you get the same error. If you do then all the AWS tags on the question are irrelevant.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes this is what I expect to happen. I want to pull in the official composer image and use it as needed.

Comment: I've since solved the issue. I've switched to another image called "composer/composer" and it just works. I've checked the manifest for this image and it's v2. For some reason the official composer image returns no manifest. That could be the issue. Regardless, I am using this new image and it works now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Removing the `composer-php` tag, as this problem is not related to Composer itself